# Can't initialize Spark Context while using sbt test

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, akka

I have written unit test cases in Spark using Scala in Specs2 framework. In some of the tests, I am creating a Spark Context and passing in functions.

```
         val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[2]")
         val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
         val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr)
         val output = Util.getHistograms(rdd, header, skipCols, nBins)
```

These tests are executing correctly in eclipse JUnit plug-in with no errors or failures, but when I run `sbt test`, I get a strange exception and the test returns with errors.

```
[info] Case 8: getHistograms should
[error]   ! return with correct output
[error]    akka.actor.InvalidActorNameException: actor name [ExecutorEndpoint] is not unique! (ChildrenContainer.scala:192)
[error] akka.actor.dungeon.ChildrenContainer$TerminatingChildrenContainer.reserve(ChildrenContainer.scala:192)
[error] akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.reserveChild(Children.scala:77)
[error] akka.actor.ActorCell.reserveChild(ActorCell.scala:369)
[error] akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.makeChild(Children.scala:202)
[error] akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.attachChild(Children.scala:42)
[error] akka.actor.ActorCell.attachChild(ActorCell.scala:369)
[error] akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.actorOf(ActorSystem.scala:552)
[error] org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv.actorRef$lzycompute$1(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:92)
[error] org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$akka$AkkaRpcEnv$$actorRef$1(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:92)
[error] org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$setupEndpoint$1.apply(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:148)
[error] org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$setupEndpoint$1.apply(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:148)
[error] org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEndpointRef.actorRef$lzycompute(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:281)
[error] org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEndpointRef.actorRef(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:281)
[error] org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEndpointRef.hashCode(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:329)
[error] org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv.registerEndpoint(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:73)
[error] org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv.setupEndpoint(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:149)
[error] org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:89)
[error] org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalBackend.scala:57)
[error] org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalBackend.start(LocalBackend.scala:119)
[error] org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:144)
[error] org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:514)
[error] UtilTest$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(UtilTest.scala:113)
[error] UtilTest$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(UtilTest.scala:111)
```

I guess because of the the SparkContext (sc) is not getting created and I am getting a null, but I can't understand what is causing this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because sbt executes all the tests together, and thus multiple SparkContext were getting created due to the running of Specifications file multiple times.
To resolve this, add a separate object and initialize your SparkContext in it. Use this sc all over the test code so that it doesn't get created multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the reason is even simpler - you cannot run mutable spark contexts in the same JVM at the same time. sbt test executes tests in parallel, meaning that if your tests all spawn a spark context, the tests will fail.

To prevent this from happening add the following to your build.sbt:

```
// super important with multiple tests running spark Contexts
parallelExecution in Test := false
```

which will result in sequential tests execution.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference

Comment: Oh, so your problem was that you're creating multiple spark contexts within a single test? if that is so consider using the BeforeAndAfter trait and using just one spark context in your test, as you suggested.